# Chrome: Remap Cmd+Click to Ctrl+Click for "open link in new window"

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, remapping

I use a lot of keyboard shortcuts, and recently I've found that pressing `Cmd` with the thumb is becoming quite painful.

I've remapped `Capslock` to `Ctrl`, and are now switching to using `Ctrl` (capslock key) for my shortcuts as it seems a lot more ergonomic.

Using the "Keyboard Shortcuts" in OSX Settings, I can remap the common menu items (Copy, Paste, etc) to use `Ctrl` rather than `Cmd` for their shortcut.

However, in browsers I also use `Cmd+Click` to open links into new tabs. I do this a lot.

How can I remap `Cmd+Click` to `Ctrl+Click` in Chrome / Firefox etc?  Is there an extension that I can use?

I use Chrome most of the time, so are mainly interested in Chrome.

**EDIT**: I use a magic mouse or a magic trackpad. So unfortunately there is no "middle click" either

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can use [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com) to simulate a middle click with the magic mouse, by clicking in the middle of the mouse. Seems to work OK so far.

I'd still prefer the remapping solution, so please post if you know of a way.